# React - Passing state as props not causing re-render on child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that initiates state and then once mounted updates it from the results of a get request

```
const [vehicles, handleVehicles] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        axios({
            //get data from backend
        }).then(({data}) => {
            handleVehicles(prevState => [...prevState, data])
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }, [])
```

I have the state passed down as a prop into a child component. In my child component I run a check to see if the vehicles array is populated...if it is I return some jsx otherwise I return nothing. My issue is that the state change won't reflect in the prop passed down and cause a re-render. It remains at an empty array unless I refresh the page.

I pass it down via

```
<RenderTableData vehicles={vehicles} />
```

My child component is:

```
const RenderTableData = (props) => {

    if (!props.vehicles[0]) {
        return null
    } else {
        return (
            props.vehicles[0].map((vehicle) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={vehicle._id}>
                        <td>{vehicle.name}</td>
                        <td>{vehicle._id}</td>
                        <td><button className="has-background-warning">Edit</button></td>
                        <td><button className="has-background-danger">Remove</button></td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })
        )
    }
}
```

How would I approach solving this?

**Edit** - It does actually work as is...For some reason the http request takes an age to return the data (and I was never patient enough to notice)...So I have a new problem now :(

Comment: Could you share the code from the child component, and also how it is being called? It might be something in there preventing the re-render

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is `prevState` but I think your problem is caused by passing to `handleVehicles` a function instead of the new value. So your code should be:

```js
    const [vehicles, handleVehicles] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        axios({
            //get data from backend
        }).then(({data}) => {
            handleVehicles([...prevState, data])
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }, [])
```

Comment: It does unfortunately continue with an error as I have no reference to PrevState if I don't pass it as an argument

Comment: The question is: is `prevState` equal to `vehicles` before inserting the new data?

Comment: Yeah, vehicles it just an empty array until i fetch the data via the get request. To avoid mutating the array I use the spread operator to update it

Comment: Yes, what I mean is if you should do `handleVehicles([...vehicles, data])` or `handleVehicles(vehicles.concat(data))`

Comment: Reading your comments in the other answer, I don't understand why do you have data is in this format but my last suggestion of using `concat` should be `handleVehicles([vehicles[0].concat(data)])`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using the map function on the object. Your child component should be like below:

```
const RenderTableData = (props) => {

if (!props.vehicles[0]) {
    return null
} else {
    return (
        props.vehicles.map((vehicle) => {
            return (
                <tr key={vehicle._id}>
                    <td>{vehicle.name}</td>
                    <td>{vehicle._id}</td>
                    <td><button className="has-background-warning">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button className="has-background-danger">Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Its a 0 indexed array full of objects I have to access

Comment: You mean the data fetched from server is like Array of Array of Objects?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a working example at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-chaplygin-jz4ot?file=/src/App.js:1340-1388). Some comments:

Your effect will run just once, after the component mounts.
If the API returns successfully, a new vehicle list is created with the previous one. But `prevState` is empty, so this is the same as `handleVehicles(data)` in this case. If you wanna spread data inside the vehicle list, don't forget to `handleVehicles(prevState => [...prevState,` **...data**`]);`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    axios({
        //get data from backend
    }).then(({data}) => {
        handleVehicles(prevState => [...prevState, data])
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}, [])
```

In your children component, you probably want to map over the vehicles list, not over the first element. So, you should remove the `[0]` in

```
const RenderTableData = (props) => {
    if (!props.vehicles[0]) {
        return null
    } else {
        return (
            props.vehicles[0].map((vehicle) => {
                return (
                    ...
                )
            })
        )
    }
}
```